# Can I create a table structure with dynamic columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, multiple-columns

I've created a stock control database which contains two tables (actually more than two, but these are the two that are relevant to my question): Stock, and Receipts

I would like the link between the stock in the stock table,and the stock in the receipts table to be a little more clearer, this would be fine if a customer could only order one item of stock per receipt, as i'd simply have a StockID column and a Quantity column in the Recipts table, with the StockID column as an FK to the ID in the Stock table, however, the customer can make a receipt with any number of items of stock on it, which would mean i'd have to have a large number of columns in the Receipts table (i.e. StockID_1, Quantity_1, StockID_2, Quantity_2 etc.)

Is there a way around this (can you have like a dynamically expanding set of columns in MySQL) within MySQL, other than what i've done at the moment, which is to have an OrderContents column with the following structure (which isn't enforced by the database or anything) StockID1xQuantity,StockID2xQuantity and so on?

I would post an image of the DB structure, but I don't have enough repuation yet. My lecturer mentioned something about that it could be done, by normalising the database into 4th or 5th normal form?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest having 3 tables:

**Stock** (StockID) + stock specific fields

**Receipt** (ReceiptID) + receipt specific fields.

**StockReceipt** (ReceiptID, StockID, Quantity) (could have a StockReceiptID, or use StockID+ReceiptID as Primary Key)

---

A solution including prices could look like:

**Stock** (StockID, Price)

**PriceHistory** (StockID, Price, Date) or (DateFrom, DateTo)

**Receipt** (ReceiptID, ReceiptDate)

**StockReceipt** (ReceiptID, StockID, Quantity)

That way you can calculate TotalStockReceiptPrice and TotalReceiptPrice for any receipt in the past.

---

I suspect this *might* be what you're looking for:

**Stock** (StockID, StockPrice)

**Receipt** (ReceiptID)

**StockReceipt** (ReceiptID, StockID, Quantity)

```
SELECT r.ReceiptID, SUM(s.StockPrice * sr.Quantity) AS ReceiptPrice
FROM Receipt r
INNER JOIN StockReceipt sr ON r.ReceiptID = sr.ReceiptID
INNER JOIN Stock s ON sr.StockID = s.StockID
GROUP BY r.ReceiptID
```

This is all very normalised (again, no idea to what normal form - 3rd?). However it only works if the StockPrice on the Stock record NEVER changes. As soon as it changes your ReceiptPrices would all reflect the new price instead of what the customer actually paid.

If the price can change, you'd need to either keep a price history table (ItemID, Price, DateTo, DateFrom) or record the StockPrice on the StockReceipt record (and then get rid of the `JOIN` to the Stock record in the above query and make it use `sr.StockPrice` instead of `s.StockPrice`)

To do the `INSERT` you posted below, you'd have to do:

```
INSERT INTO StockReceipts  (ReceiptID, StockID, Quantity, TotalStockPrice) 
SELECT 1, 99, 2, s.StockPrice
FROM Stock s 
WHERE s.StockID = 99
```

However it's quite likely that whatever is issuing this receipt (and triggers the `INSERT`) already knows the price so could just insert the value.

Comment: This is normalising the database, but I couldn't tell you to what normal form.

Comment: That might work, thanks :) Making StockID+ReciptID as a compound primary key makes sense.

Comment: This is standard 3rd normal form, a regular many-to-many relationship. One stock item can be on many receipts and one receipt can contain many stock items.

Comment: @nielsm, thanks for the info, one of these days I really need to go back and read up on normalisation

Comment: Is it compliant (If I go with a StockReceipt table) for me to have a Total Price column for the entire order in the Recipts table, as well as a TotalStockPrice column in the StockRecipt Table, which stores the total price for however many of that item of stock has been ordered?

Comment: Compliant in terms of normalisation? I'd say TotalStockPrice on StockReceipts would make sense - since the Price on the StockRecord could change, but the amount the customer paid at the time would never change. Having a TotalPrice column on Receipts table goes against normalisation though. It should be calculated from the StockReceipts table. Since the TotalPrice on Receipts table should always = SUM(TotalStockPrice) on StockReceipts, if you ever needed to change TotalStockPrice, you'd have to separated update TotalPrice to make them match up.

Comment: I suppose a further normalised solution to having TotalStockPrice on StockReceipts would be to have a history table for StockPrice. That way you could always calculate how much a StockReceipt cost given the ReceiptDate. Gonna update my answer.

Comment: The SUM(TotalStockPrice) thing makes sense. How would I go about implementing that though? I'd have to first create the Receipt in the Receipt table first (to get the ReciptID for the row to insert into the StockRecipts table), but I wouldn't have a TotalStockPrice in the StockRecipts table yet though to calculate in the TotalPrice in the Receipts Table. Would I just have to create the record in Receipts first, with a null value for the TotalPrice, and then UPDATE it later, once i've inserted the rows into the StockReceiptsTable?

Comment: From a normalisation standpoint, I definitely wouldn't store TotalPrice anywhere in the database. Just calculate it when you need it. The fact you'd need to update it later (as you rightly say) is a sign it's not normalised. In a fully normalised database you're never going to store any value that can be calculated from other data in the database (and that would need to change if the other data changed)

Comment: Right, so instead of storing TotalPrice in the Receipt table, I just generate it on the fly from the TotalStockPrice values in the StockReceipts Table? That makes sense.

Comment: OK, I'm trying to dynamically calculate the TotalStockPrice when I insert a new row into the ReciptsTable, with the following query. Is this possible in SQL? INSERT INTO stockreceipts R (ReceiptID, StockID, Quantity, TotalStockPrice) VALUES (1,1,2,Quantity * (SELECT price FROM stock S WHERE S.StockID = R.StockID)) I hope you understand what i'm trying to do in that query :$

Comment: Yeah it's completely possible in SQL, bah I'd invite you to chat but you don't have the rep. I'll update my answer with some examples.

Comment: This is a link to my ERD: http://i.imgur.com/NTTvPbd.png including the StockRecipts Table. I've taken any reference to total order price out of the receipts table now too. Username refers to the username of the staff member making the order/receipt.

Comment: With regards to your edit with the Joins, it has to be an insert statement (unless your query also inserts records into the StockReceipt Row). And the lecturers suggestion was only a quick thing, I didn't explain it to him in detail, it's for a project i'm working on.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood and assume this was some assignment where everyone was given the same problem to solve. That query was just to get the TotalPrice for each receipt. I have to go now I'm afraid, will check back in a couple of hours.

Comment: No, sorry. I think my lecturer may have got the wrong end of the stick anyway. I just need to find out how to do a nested insert now, along the lines of the INSERT query I posted above.

Comment: Didn't notice that query, will have a quick look now. Ah right, when I was writing that other query I realised, there is no point in storing TotalStockPrice. Store StockPrice on StockReceipt table (if you think StockPrice will change, if StockPrice won't change then you don't need to keep anything price related on StockReceipt). I'll give you an example of how to stock TotalStock price anyway though.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. With a StockPriceHistory table, what would the Primary Key be, would I just have to create a StockPriceID field? This is my new ERD: http://i.imgur.com/oLRSn95.png

Comment: gtg now sorry. will report back

Comment: Well i've implemented a StockPriceHistory table, but in order to get that to update automatically via a trigger, i've kept a currentprice record in the Stock table.

Comment: Hey john, yeah thats the right way to do it (ah I see I didn't show stock price in the StockTable but in my head it was there ;) ). I still can't decide how I'd handle the receipt prices in a production system, but a price history table will do the job. Anything else in particular you need advice on?

Answer (score 0):

No, relational databases do not allow dynamic columns. The definition of a relational table is that it has a header that name the columns, and *every* row has the same columns.

Your technique of repeating the groups of stock columns is a violation of First Normal Form, and it also has a lot of practical problems, for instance:

- How do you know how many extra columns to create?
- How do you search for a given value when you don't know which column it's in?
- How do you enforce uniqueness?

The simplest solution is as @OGHaza described, store extra stock/quantity data on *rows* in another table. That way the problems above are solved.

- You don't need to create extra columns, just extra rows, which is easy with INSERT.
- You can search for a given value over *one* column to find it.
- You can put constraints on the column.

If you really want to understand relational concepts, a nice book that is easy to read is: [SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449316409) by C. J. Date.

---

There are also situations where you want to expand a table definition with dynamic columns that aren't repeating -- they're just new attributes. This is not relational, but it doesn't mean that we don't need some data modeling techniques to handle the scenario you describe.

For this type of problem, you might like to read my presentation [Extensible Data Modeling with MySQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling), for an overview of different solutions, and their pros and cons.

---

PS: Fourth and Fifth normal form have *nothing* to do with this scenario. Your lecturer obviously doesn't understand them.